# delegate / event c#

Tags: c#, события

вопрос простой но для профи.
значит есть event и пара методов для добавления и удаления.

если делать  -= какойтoМетод;  при том что этот метод туда не был добавлен ранее, что то может произойти? к примеру может он что-то другое удалить в этом событии?

Comment: [Ничего страшного не произойдет](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678272/312041)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В исходниках есть проверка на существование, так что ты просто потратишь таким образом процессорное время:

```
protected virtual Delegate RemoveImpl(Delegate d)
{
   return (d.Equals(this)) ? null : this;
}

public static Delegate Remove(Delegate source, Delegate value)
{
        if (source == null)
            return null;

        if (value == null)
            return source;

        if (!InternalEqualTypes(source, value))
            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_DlgtTypeMis"));

        return source.RemoveImpl(value);
 }
```